# How to solve Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am trying with coustom constrain

**Menubar class :**

```
import UIKit

class ManuBar: UIView {
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

}

extension UIView {
    func addConstraintsWithFormat(format: String, views: UIView...) {
        var viewsDictionary = [String: UIView]()
        for (index, view) in views.enumerate() {
            let key = "v\(index)"
            view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            viewsDictionary[key] = view
        }

        addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(format, options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary))
    }
}
```

**View controller :**

```
import UIKit

    class ViewController: UIViewController {

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


            setupManuBar();

        }

        let menuBar : ManuBar = {
           let mb = ManuBar()
            return mb
        }()

        private func setupManuBar(){

            view.addSubview(menuBar)

            view.addConstraintsWithFormat("H:|[v0]|",views : menuBar)
            view.addConstraintsWithFormat("V:|-16-[v0(40)]|",views : menuBar)
        }


    }
```

[image]

> Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
>       Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
>       Try this: 
>           (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
>           (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or

```
constraints and fix it.
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ff891d27c70 V:|-(16)-[Tab_Menu_Bar_Programmatically.ManuBar:0x7ff891d19f30]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7ff891d1b570 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ff891d27f40 V:[Tab_Menu_Bar_Programmatically.ManuBar:0x7ff891d19f30(40)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ff891d0fc50 V:[Tab_Menu_Bar_Programmatically.ManuBar:0x7ff891d19f30]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7ff891d1b570 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ff891d1c8e0 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' V:[UIView:0x7ff891d1b570(736)]>"
)
```

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint

**if your need more information let me know**

Comment: Please post a screenshot of you constraints to your question. Let me know if you can't figure out how to do that.

Comment: @DanLevy update my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot **view** in `view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false`, thus you are setting the translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints on the cell and not on the individual views.

**Change the for loop to**

```
for (index, view) in views.enumerate(){
                let key = "v\(index)"
                view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
                viewsDictionry[key] = view

            }
```

I would also look at [lazy loading](https://medium.com/swift-programming/how-to-do-proper-lazy-loading-in-swift-b8bc57dbc7b9#.hw5y5hy9p)  the views by adding the lazy keyword.

**Update :**

You significantly changed your code though. I tested on your first example, and it worked. Your problem now is: `view.addConstraintsWithFormat("V:|-16-[v0(40)]|",views : menuBar)` Your are basically setting the height of the menubar twice. You are setting it to a fixed height of **40**, but you are also telling it to stretch according to superview. **16** pixels top **space + 0** pixels at bottom. Remove the `|` at the end

like this way:

```
 view.addConstraintsWithFormat("H:|[v0]|",views : menuBar) 
 view.addConstraintsWithFormat("V:|-16-[v0(40)]",views : menuBar)
```

Comment: Yes , significant changed , sorry for that! When I remove the | at the end then exception throwing

Answer (score 0):

I would look at adding a height constraint to the thumbnail image. Look at either vertical or horizontal constraints not fully being satisfied and make sure every view has a size and a position defined. Also make sure there are no conflicting constraints in a layout file if you are using one.